# Struts 2 if tag : test with a constant

Tags: if-statement, struts2, constants

I'm tying to make the following code:

```
<s:if test="%{#beanVar == com.mycompany.project.NOT_REGISTERED} ">
 <td>NOT REGISTRED</td>
</s:if>
```

where **com.mycompany.project.NOT_REGISTERED** is a class static field :

```
public static final long NOT_REGISTERED == 0;
```

I can't find in the Struts2 documentation the way to expose a constant in runtime evaluation.

Thanks in advance for your help.

P.S : I wouldn't like to use old-school construct <% %>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From OGNL Basics :

> Accessing static properties
>   OGNL supports accessing static properties as well as static methods.
>
> By default, Struts 2 is configured to disallow this--to enable OGNL's
>   static member support you must set the
>   struts.ognl.allowStaticMethodAccess constant to true via any of the
>   Constant Configuration methods.
>
> OGNL's static access looks like this:
>
> ```
> @some.package.ClassName@FOO_PROPERTY
> @some.package.ClassName@someMethod()
> ```
>
> However, XWork allows you to avoid having to specify the full package
>   name and call static properties and methods of your action classes
>   using the "vs" prefix:
>
> ```
> @vs@FOO_PROPERTY @vs@someMethod()
> @vs1@FOO_PROPERTY @vs1@someMethod()
> @vs2@BAR_PROPERTY @vs2@someOtherMethod()
> ```
>
> "vs" stands for "value stack". The important thing to note here is
>   that if the class name you specify is just "vs", the class for the
>   object on the top of the stack is used. If you specify a number after
>   the "vs" string, an object's class deeper in the stack is used
>   instead.

Regards,

Comment: Strange, I've added **struts.ognl.allowStaticMethodAccess = true** and used the syntax that you described, and it didn't work. Maybe the reason is that I'm trying to access the static field and not a static method?

Comment: The value from test is already evaluated as an OGNL expression, try: test="beanVar == @com.mycompany.project@NOT_REGISTERED}"

Comment: Cool, glad it does, you can accept the answer as valid then ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
<s:if test="%{#beanVar == @com.mycompany.project@NOT_REGISTERED}">
  <td>NOT REGISTRED</td>
</s:if>
```

**@** is missing.